# Crear un contador dentro de xpath?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, scraping, xpath

Hola ¿Alguien sabe como **crear un contador dentro del xpath** para ir incrementando las filas?

Aquí dejo el código:

```
cli = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                            '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/a')
```

Quiero que `html/body/div[2]` en el siguiente bucle sea `html/body/div[3]`. etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el método `.format()` de los strings para pasarle el contador. Por ejemplo imaginemos que quieres introducir el contador en el primer `div[1]`, tu código quedaría así:

```
contador = 0

cli = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
  '/html/body/div[{}]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/a'.format(contador)
)
```

Al ejecutarse, el `xpath` quedaría así:

**Salida**

```
'/html/body/div[0]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/a'
```

Como puedes ver, la variable `contador` es introducida en donde se encuentran las llaves.

También se puede usar `format()` poniendo una `f` delante del string y el nombre de la variable entre las llaves, de tal forma que quedaría así:

```
contador = 0

cli = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
  f'/html/body/div[{contador}]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/a'
)
```